# PHP redirect with header() is opening redirected page within first page

Tags: php, html, browser, redirect, header

I am writing a PHP page that contains outputs, and then an if then statement that results in:

```
ob_start();
header('Location: http://www.mydomain.com/');
ob_end_flush();
```

There are no errors, but the page it is redirecting to is opening up within the main page. You can see the top half of the main page, then the entire contents of the page it's redirecting to, and then the bottom half of the main page. It all appears on the same screen. This is really causing havoc for my site. How can I just make it simply go to the new page?

Comment: This sounds weird. Anyway, put the `header()` before anything is output, and `die()`, then there should be no problems

Comment: What is it your are actually trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

It really not make any sense to output the buffer and make a redirect within.

I suggest to make all the checks you need to assure you need to output content or redirect, and then make one of them.

You should also stop the script execution after changing the header location. Something like :

```
if($needToRedirect){
      header('Location: http://www.mydomain.com/');
      exit();
}else{
      ob_end_flush();
}
```